# Is there a way to get WebStorm to autocomplete tag attribute values?

Tags: webstorm

I'm trying to get WebStorm to autocomplete some HTML attribute values while working with Angular Material.

Editor > Inspections > HTML > Unknown HTML tag attribute

I added some attributes here like `flex`, `flex-md` and `layout`, but how can I get autocomplete for a situation like below?

```
<div layout="can be row or column"></div>
```

A layout's value is either a `row` or `column`, so I want row and column to appear when I type layout="row/column here", is it possible?

I'm using WebStorm 12 EAP.

Answer (score 3):

I've done some research too, but found nothing answering this question. Looks like you just can add custom tag, which will be automatically completed, e.g. to`layout=""`, but not their value.
You can't change the behaviour of autocompletion at the moment, see this old [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-459)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try to import. In the TypeScript context, WebStorm can generate import statements for modules, classes, and any other symbol that can be exported and called as a type.

[**Here's**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/completing-tag-names.html?origin=old_help) link from official documentation.